# How to cancel mergemap while source is array

Tags: rxjs, mergemap

Hello i use mergemap from rxjs. I use array of object.

```
const list = [{name:'test',url:'https.....'}.....]
const source = from(list)
.pipe(mergeMap(getFile, null, 4))
.subscribe(saveDB);
```

In my getFile function I do downlaod file using axios to blob and in subscribe save.
Now Lets say i wan to cancel all process for now i just return promise to reject, or if continue resolve.
Is there better way ?

My goal is to downloading new files.
getFile

```
return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      //change on click for example
      if (!downloadInProgress) {
        reject("finish");
      }
      const dataToSave = {
        ...val,
        blob: new Blob([response.data], { type: val.type }),
      };
      resolve(dataToSave);

})
```

Comment: You'd have to use a `CancelToken` (https://github.com/axios/axios#cancellation) to cancel a request. Please post the code of your `getFile` function.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve. You are trying to cancel all files being downloaded or you are trying to cancel specific ones? Or just select certain ones to get downloaded and others not?

Comment: When user click cancel i want to cancel all future and current download. But files processed just move to subscribe as in example resolve.